# Run script every time the system's default gateway changes?

Tags: network, script, vpn

I'd like to run a script every time my mac's default gateway changes. For example, I'd like it to run if my internet connection changes from Wi-Fi to ethernet, if it disconnects or reconnects, or if I connect or disconnect from a VPN.

On a more technical level, I'd like the script to run when an entry is added, removed, or modified in the system routing table for `default` or `0/1`, and possibly a few other relevant entries. Something that runs any time the routing table changes would be acceptable too, since I could just detect if the change is something I care about.

Is there any way to do this, other than just polling at some short interval and checking to see if the default gateway has changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor *files* like the following for changes and act accordingly:

- `/private/var/run/resolv.conf`
- `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist`
- `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`

You can use a **Launch Agent** with a **WatchPaths** *key*, however, see the note regarding its use in the *manual page* for `launchd.plist`.  I will say that in spite of the note, I have not had issues with a **WatchPaths** *key* in my **Launch Agents** that I currently use. YMMV

If you are going to use **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend you read the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`.

You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`man command`*, then press **enter**, or **for easier reading**, just type *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Or use a *third-party application* like **EventScripts**.

It can trigger an **AppleScript** *script* or a *shell script* with *events* like:

- Internet became available
- Internet became unavailable
- External IP address changed
- Wireless network changed

And many more types  of *events*.

Have a look at [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html), it's [$5.99 at the US App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12), but a free demo is downloadable from the developers website.

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of **EventScripts**, just a satisfied user of the product.</sub>